# How to remove blue shade from dropdown

Tags: javascript

I'm back for another beatin' ;)

So I have a hamburger with a dropdown menu, When opening the burger, a blue shade appears around the entire dropdown and the hamburger. I think is the focus part in the script and cannot figure it out. I would like to rid the focus thingy.

```
$(".dropdown").click(function () {
    $(this).attr("tabindex", 1).focus();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle(300);
});
$(".dropdown").focusout(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").slideUp(300);
});
```

I also have the CSS if needed. Thank you for reading. Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's CSS. Just try

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  outline: none;
}
```

buuuuut, it's there for a reason. Outlines exist for accesibility reasons. You should not remove them.

Comment: That worked. Ty. I get the accessibility but the blue shade can't be there in my face every time I click the burger. No?

Comment: Well, it should be there to be accessible. But I must say not many websites are created with accessibility in mind. I just wanted to point out what it does and why it's there. You can remove it if you want.